# Изменение структуры массива php

Tags: php

Есть массив `$res`, который имеет структура следующего типа

```
(
    [1262] => 2
    [1258] => 2
)
```

Можно ли его изменить так, чтобы он имел следующую структуру

```
[0] = (
    ["ID"] => "1262"
    ["A"] => 2
)
[1] = (
    ["ID"] => "1258"
    ["A"] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = ['1262' => 2, '1258' => 2];
$new_array = [];

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $new_array[] = ['ID' => $k, 'A' => $v];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = array(1262 => 2,1258 => 2);
$out = array();
foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
    $out[] = array('ID' => $k, 'A' => $v);
}
print_r($out);
```